Error while saving entity in AWS neptune with neo4j-ogm
I try to evaluated if i can use Quarkus neo4j-ogm library with AWS Neptune but it fails with following error when saving
2024-06-28 10:20:18,900 DEBUG [org.neo.ogm.dri.bol.req.BoltRequest] (executor-thread-1) Request: UNWIND $rows as row MERGE (n:`Dummy`{id: row.props.id}) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, $type as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeRef=-1, props={businessId=toto1, name=toto}}]}

2024-06-28 10:20:18,900 DEBUG [org.neo.ogm.dri.bol.req.BoltRequest] (executor-thread-1) Request: UNWIND $rows as row MERGE (n:`Dummy`{id: row.props.id}) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, $type as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeRef=-1, props={businessId=toto1, name=toto}}]}
2024-06-28T10:20:18.974+02:00
2024-06-28 10:20:18,973 WARN  [org.neo.ogm.ses.Neo4jSession] (executor-thread-1) Error executing query : "BoltProtocol.unexpectedException" - "Unexpected server exception 'Property access over ambiguous type is not supported in this release.'". Rolling back transaction.

Code to save is done with :
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.save(dummy);

With Dummy class :
@NodeEntity
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Dummy {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotNull
    @Id
    String businessId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    String name;
 
}

I try to look in source code where 'Property access over ambiguous type is not supported in this release' should be raised but i can't find it

The Property access over ambiguous type is not supported in this release exception is thrown by Neptune.  This likely occurs when you're trying to unwind a list of maps in a CREATE or MERGE query and Neptune isn't able to directly translate the un-wound values as maps.
Example:
UNWIND $people as person
CREATE (p1:Person
{
    name: person.name,
    address: person.address,
    phone: person.phone
}
WITH p1, person.purchases as purchases
    UNWIND purchases as purchase
    CREATE (p2:Purchase)  
    SET p2 += purchase
    CREATE (p1)-[:BOUGHT]->(p2)

In this case, purchase in the second half of the query is seen as an ambiguous type.  In order to declare this as a map, you may need to use:
SET p2 += removeKeyFromMap(purchase, "")

This will ensure the value of purchase is seen as a map.
This is just one example of where this type of exception may get thrown.  So if you're seeing this exception from your query, you may want to investigate areas in the query where an injected value could be seen as ambiguous.
